# Mathematica steals focus after finishing computation

Tags: notebooks, user-interface

This is happening after I upgraded to 11.3. I am on Linux Mint.

Whenever mathematica finishes evaluating the cells in a Notebook, if that Notebook is minimized, it will pop up and steal focus from my other windows. This is very disruptive.

Is anyone experiencing a similar behavior? How can I disable it? I would like the Mathematica Notebook window to remain minimized after it finished the computation. Perhaps it could flash in the taskbar, but stealing focus is definitely too much.

Comment: In the "System Settings / Windows / Behaviour"  I have  "Window focus mode" set to "Mouse", so that focus remains with which ever window the mouse is over.  If I change it to "Click" I see the behaviour you describe.  I see there is also an option "Prevent Focus Stealing".  That seems to fix it.

Answer (score 6):

In the "System Settings / Windows / Behaviour" I have "Window focus mode" set to "Mouse", so that focus remains with which ever window the mouse is over.

If I change it to "Click" I see the behaviour you describe.

There is also an option "Prevent Focus Stealing", that seems to fix your problem.