# Is there a way to disable the "Formatting Notebook Contents" panel?

Tags: front-end, dynamic, gui-construction

Mathematica loves telling the user that it is "Formatting Notebook Contents" during DataModeler model searches. The problem is that, even though Mathematica is in the background, that panel pops up front & center and steals focus from the application actually being worked upon.

Needless to say, my users get ticked off at this intrusive behavior on the part of the front end.

In my opinion, there is a design flaw in the sense that WRI should not steal focus if it is a background app.

That said, is there a way to either suppress the message entirely or to not steal focus from the foreground app? Alternately, is there a way to detect that Mathematica is in the background to intelligently suppress front end graphics?

Thanks.

Comment: how are you starting mathematica? clicking on a *.nb? downloading a *.nb clicking open? launching from the start menu or desktop shortcut? windows startup folder? are you starting mathematica from a shell script or some kind of automation or toolchain? if you are launching mathematica from the command line via shell script, what arguments are you passing in? the shortest answer I can give you is that if you are developing a .net application on windows, this would be an easy thing to fix. or you can wait for WRI to fix it. decide if you are more concerned with "always on top" or the focus.

Comment: DataModelerGUI[ ] (100% Mma) is normally launched via a palette click with Mathematica running. The user beating me about this is running MacOS on an 18-core iMac Pro with 16 sub-kernels crunching their model searches independently. While the model search is going, she is trying to work with other applications (Mail, Keynote, Pages, Tableau, etc.). The goal is any solution which doesn't impede productive work on the part of the user — killing the panel, having it have lower priority than the front app or simply an ability for Mathematica to recognize it is not front  are all equally good.

Comment: @MarkKotanchek Yes, I got annoyed by these useless popups, too. Try something like FrontEndExecute @ FrontEnd`NotebookSuspendScreenUpdates[nb] .
No guarantee, though. I also optimized programmatic notebook generation.
Feel free to contact me if needed.

Comment: Is there a good simple representative example that shows the problem? Ideally an example that works on a stock unmodified Mathematica installation? I don't fully understand the problem from the description, but I am wondering if scheduled tasks can at least avoid these problems.

Comment: @RolfMertig Thanks Rolf. I sent you an email but it might have gone to junk mail.

Comment: @ArnoudBuzing Ahh, there's the kicker — problems only show up when edge conditions are explored. The issue is that the (mostly useless) popup panel informing the user that the front end is formatting appears higher in the window stack than the application which is foremost from the user perspective. In addition to being supremely irritating, their keystrokes in Word/Powerpoint/Tableaux/etc. don't go where intended.

The solution seems to be to hide Mathematica but that should not be necessary. If you'd like, we can have a web session and I should be able to demonstrate the issue.

Comment: Any update on this?  I made a little stock price tracker (using python for the websocket) and I periodically update some DateListPlots from data python saves to a temporary file...  feeding it directly from python to Mma is my next goal.  I'd obviously like this to run in the background but the Formatting Notebook Contents popup keeps interrupting other work I'm trying to do.  This is on an older MacBook Pro but normally does not have this problem.

Comment: @EricMock Mathematica (at least on the Mac) is not a good citizen in that its panels pop to the front of all applications rather than just for Mathematica. Hiding Mathematica (cmd-h on MacOS) does suppress the flickering and the downside of not being able to stash a window off in a corner of a screen to track progress — which would be something that I suspect you care about dearly. I did not chase down Rolf's suggestion since I'm in the midst of a massive code tuning exercise for DataModeler.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this is a setting you can turn off. There is a similar post here that will probably work for you. I do not have an OSX machine to test this myself.

[Mathematica steals focus after finishing computation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/176349/mathematica-steals-focus-after-finishing-computation)

Comment: It doesn't appear that MacOS has such a feature — although, it may be buried in their system preferences. You did inspire me to tell the user to hide Mathematica to see if that helped and it appears all of the subkernels keep crunching without the formatting panel popping up. There is still a flickering that happens so that doesn't appear to be a complete solution. Of course, I'd prefer a solution that doesn't require user intervention so I don't think we are there yet for addressing the issue.